# Python: trying to copy files from a directory into another directory

Tags: python

I am trying to copy files from one directory into another. finding the users home path and joining with their 'downloads' folder, I want to copy their 'readme' files to the current working directory. When I run the program, it completes then no files are moved...

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import shutil

os.chdir(os.pathabspath(os.path.dirname(__name__)))

def activities():
    user = os.path.expanduser('~')
    src = os.path.join(user, 'Downloads')
    dst = Path('.')
    for filename in os.listdir(src):
        if filename.startswith('readme'):
           shutil.copy2(src + filename, dst)
activities()
```

Comment: Unindent your call to the function in the last line as a start.

Comment: And most probably you want to have `filename in` not `filename is`.

Comment: Additional typo in `startswith`

Comment: indentations are very important in Python - remove spaces in last line with `activities()`. Currently last line is inside `def activities():`

Comment: sorry about typos, been working on this for days...in the program I have no typos.

Comment: BTW: next time use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what values are in variables - it helps to find problem.

Comment: is this your original version or you change it with our comments ? Always show code which you really run and don't change it later - because you can ask for solution for code which works correctly - and it makes no sense.

Comment: you should use `os.path.join()` instead of `+` because `src + filename` can gives you path `.readme` when you need `./readme`

Comment: sorry, new to this. I was making edits and will not anymore. what makes no sense? the code?

Comment: when you change code to create working version then our comments and answers doesn't fit to code and it useless for people which will read it later. And all question  makes no sense. Better upped  new version (and new inforamtion) at the end with text `EDIT:` or `UDPATE:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import shutil

os.chdir(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__name__)))

def activities():
    user = os.path.expanduser('~')
    src = os.path.join(user, 'Downloads')
    dst = Path('.')
    for filename in os.listdir(src):
        if filename.startswith('readme'):
           shutil.copy(f'{src}/{filename}', dst)
activities()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I will give it a go, and much appreciated! I've been frustrated with this one

Comment: quick question: how do I copy all the 'readme' files? My issue is not all the 'readme' files are not lower case. Also using 'f' @ shutilcopy do import string?

Comment: you could use a regex expression from the `re` module with an Ignorecase flag, that will ensure that all readme -no matter what case it they are in- are found